# Java - How to set a String dynamically during runtime

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string-utils

I have to build an SQL query where I have to replace two params in the String.

- The String variable **CLEAN_CSV_PATH** which represents a path
- The String variable **LINES_TERMINATED_OS**  which represents a the escape character \r\n that are needed for windows or linux, depends.

The params are provided during Main execution with the Scanner class.

This is my SQL String :

```
private static String LOAD_ALL_ALIASES = //

        "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + CLEAN_CSV_PATH + "' INTO TABLE plantbiocore.Alias " //
                + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " //
                + "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"' "
                + "LINES TERMINATED BY '" + LINES_TERMINATED_OS + "'"
                + "IGNORE 1 LINES " //
                + "(locus_id, organism_id, variable, alias) "; //



 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 CLEAN_CSV_PATH = scanner.next() // Here the CLEAN_CSV_PATH does not appear in my LOAD_ALL_ALIASES
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called PreparedStatement in java. Google it, there are many examples of using this class.
The other problem is that you are setting CLEAN_CSV_PATH after you used it to set LOAD_ALL_ALIASES. It can't work in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the things in the reverse way.
First set `CLEAN_CSV_PATH` with the scanner. Then resolve your String with.
To allow to create queries with different `CLEAN_CSV_PATH`,  you could extract it into a method that accepts a parameter.

```
public void foo(){
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   String csvPath = scanner.next()
   String query = getQuery(csvPath);         
   // ...
}

private static String getQuery(String csvPath){

       return "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + csvPath + "' INTO TABLE plantbiocore.Alias " //
                + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " //
                + "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"' "
                + "LINES TERMINATED BY '" + LINES_TERMINATED_OS + "'"
                + "IGNORE 1 LINES " //
                + "(locus_id, organism_id, variable, alias) "; //
}
```

Note that `LINES_TERMINATED_OS` could be replaced by `System.lineSeparator()` that returns at runtime the OS dependent line separator.

Answer (score 0):

Write it in the right sequence then it will work fine:

```
    String LOAD_ALL_ALIASES;
    String CLEAN_CSV_PATH;
    String LINES_TERMINATED_OS;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    CLEAN_CSV_PATH = scanner.next();
    LINES_TERMINATED_OS = scanner.next();

    LOAD_ALL_ALIASES = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + CLEAN_CSV_PATH + "' INTO TABLE plantbiocore.Alias " //
            + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " //
            + "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\"' "
            + "LINES TERMINATED BY '" + LINES_TERMINATED_OS + "'"
            + "IGNORE 1 LINES " //
            + "(locus_id, organism_id, variable, alias) ";
```